# Java/Android front-end client and node js backend server?

Tags: javascript, java, android, node.js

Is it possible to do this? Or perhaps, the question I should ask, is it feasible?

Or would it be better off to just stick with Java/Android front-end and Java back end server?

Would a node js backend be practical for multiplayer games? Or perhaps just for web applications that do not require much

And if it (java-nodejs) is practical for multiplayer games, how would one go about getting a java client to be able to communicate with a node js server?

Answer (score 0):

If you're building an API, you don't have to worry about the language in wich you write it, the way to communicate with it will remain the same (UDP/HTTP/WS request).
Nevertheless, you're creating a multiplayer game, so you will need good performance for the back-end.

NodeJS is good, very good ! Erlang is better ;)

Comment: I don't know about making an API, I was thinking more of some sort of backend engine that uses node JS and just implementing that. Like for example you have Unity3d for front end games, even though it uses C#, you don't actually make the engine itself, you use it

Comment: Yes but when you want to connect your players to each other (even when you use an engine), you have to implement a web server or use a web service .. ?

Comment: I have no idea, wouldn't you just connect to the server and everything is done there? Players dont need to connect to each other directly

Comment: Yes you do, each player connect to the server and the server share the informations. So, the server has to be fast and strong if you don't want your users to have lags,

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is feasible. Node is very efficient and fast in handling requests. Since it works on a event based model its great for server side. 
If you are working with Android and NodeJs as the server side I can help with this:

You can use Volley in Android to make a json `POST` or `GET` request.

And for the NODE JS you can use node's built-in `http` module to create a simple HTTP server and then receive data from the req object.

```
const http=require('http');
const stringDecoder=require('string_decoder').StringDecoder;

var httpServer=http.createServer(function(req,res){    
    unifinedServer(req,res);
});
//Just another method. 
var unifinedServer=function(req,res){

    var decoder=new stringDecoder('utf-8');
    var buffer='';
    //reading the post data. 
    req.on('data',function(data){
        buffer+=decoder.write(data);
    });
    //Reading of data is completed. 
    req.on('end',function(){
        buffer+=decoder.end(); 
    // Do what ever you want to do with the POST data. 
    });    
}
//The Server is listening on a specific port. 
httpServer.listen(7000,function(){
    console.log("Server is now listening on Port..."+7000);
});
```

For the Android Code you can do this with volley:

```
    String url = "http://example.com";

    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest
            (Request.Method.POST, url, postJsonObject, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            mTextView.setText("Response: " + response.toString());
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            // TODO: Handle error

        }
    });

// Access the RequestQueue through your singleton class.
MySingleton.getInstance(this).addToRequestQueue(jsonObjectRequest);
```